# What Ripple API libraries are available?

Tags: development, api, ripple, library

I am wondering, what libraries are out there for communicating with Ripple through its API (either websocket or JSON RPC)?

Answer (score 3):

- Ripple labs have created a number of [GitHub repositories](https://github.com/ripple) relating to Ripple, including [ripple-lib](https://github.com/ripple/ripple-lib) for JavaScript and a work in progress [ripple-lib-java](https://github.com/ripple/ripple-lib-java) for Java.
- [Rubble Labs](http://blog.rubblelabs.com/) have released their [ripple library](https://github.com/rubblelabs/ripple) for Golang
- [CodeShark](https://github.com/CodeShark) has released [a C++ library](https://github.com/CodeShark/ripple-lib-cpp) for communicating with Ripple through a websocket

Answer (score 2):

There is a Dart library as well. Even though it's not 100% finished yet, it works quite well.

https://github.com/stevenroose/ripple-lib-dart